# allowing only your own ip address with nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I am managing a subdomain using nginx conf files. I am able to get a working subdomain up, and deny access to it (resulting in 403) by including `deny all;`. However, when I try to add `allow 1.2.3.4;` (not posting my real IP address) right above it (this is where I understand you have to put it to allow access to your own IP address), I am still getting 403 when I try to access the subdomain on my browser (in firefox private mode). I got my IP address through https://www.whatismyip.com/, and I am using the one given under "My Public IPv4 is: ". Is this the correct IP address I should be using? If not how should I go about finding the right IP address to allow?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help if you want to access your resource via nginx **[locally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)**. You should put it in the root block of a subdomain.

```
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all;
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. Is there a way to check what my IP address is being considered as when I hit that site? It uses ingress/traefik so maybe that could influence things.

Comment: Something is wrong with your other configuration, not an IP address. Could you paste the whole code?